# MS Access, link a combo box selection to a list box entry on same form

Tags: ms-access

I have a question on MS Access. In a form I use for closing out work orders, I'd like to have the Part # combo box show only the items associated to the work order highlighted in a list box above on the same form. I'm fairly novice with Access, please bear with me.

The row source string currently is:

> `SELECT [Part Serial #].[Part #], [Part Serial #].[New Kit #], [Part
>   Serial #].[Serial #], [Part Serial #].[WO #] FROM [Part Serial #]
>   ORDER BY [WO #] DESC`.

I would like it to show only parts associated to the WO# that is highlighted in a list box selection on the same form.

Comment: What do you want ordered by the WO#? Do you want a second (seperate) list box that only shows the parts for the selected WO#? Will selecting something from your combo box populate the second list box?

Comment: I stated that incorrectly. I want only the parts associated with the selected WO# from the list box to show up in the combo box.

Comment: Let me try to rework this.

I find and hightlight the WO # that I am going to close out. I have to manually select a particular part associate with the WO # highlighted above. Sometimes I have to do a lot of scrolling to get down to the WO #. I'd LOVE that it only shows parts related to the WO # hightlighted in the list box above. Would make like so much easier.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean now.  You would have to tie that Part to that WO# somehow to do this.  Then use the statements below in correlation with .RowSource = SQL Statement.

Answer (score 0):

Is it MultiSelect?  You would have to put a WHERE clause in that SQL statement like "WHERE Part# = me.MyListBox.SelectedItem", or something.  If it's a MultiSelect, then you have to first loop through the listbox to find all the selected items and put them into an array, and then use that array in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Do you mean the row source type? It is Table/Query. I don't quite follow. I'm just wrapping up the intro to MS Access class. I don't know a lot of the jargon yet.

Comment: Some listboxes are "multiselect"; they allow you to highlight more than one item if you set MultiSelect to "Yes" in the Properties box.

Comment: I can only highlight one item at a time in the listbox by left clicking on it. Multi Select is set to None

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe looking form something like this?

It auto populates my fields below when you use the `Name_of_list_Click()`

[image]
[image]

Comment: We have a very primitive design.
/br
You can see in screen shot that I have the WO # 1237 highlighted in the list box for WO #.

When I click on the down arrow for the Part # combo box, it lists every items associated with every WO #. The lastest WO # created is 1240. I have to now scroll down for each part that I want to enter information for before closing. I'd like for this to just show the items associated only with the WO # highlighted above

!http://i518.photobucket.com/albums/u348/jbjetta/MicrosoftAccess-WOTriQOnSite2011DatabaseAccess2007_2013-06-07_09-56-58_zps7ecea778.jpg